# Unable to import python modules from different directories

Tags: python, module, package, python-import

I have a below Directory structure

```
/opt/juno/
+/opt/juno/__init__.py 
+/opt/juno/lib/__init__.py
+/opt/juno/lib/gen_cert_request.py-Class CertDB->def Generate_cert()
+/opt/juno/tests/acceptance/cli_tests/cert-cli/test1.py
```

test1.py is my pytest functions, where i need to call Generate_cert function ,  But i am unable to import the modules.

I created `__init__.py` in /opt/juno, /opt/juno/lib, /opt/juno/tests/, /opt/juno/tests/acceptance/, /opt/juno/tests/acceptance,  /opt/juno/tests/acceptance/cli-tests/, /opt/juno/tests/acceptance/cli-tests/cert-cli, Directory.

Any help on how i can call generate_cert function in test1.py ?

I tried Below

```
[root@pkiserver1 pki-cert-cli]# pwd
/opt/juno/tests/acceptance/cli-tests/pki-cert-cli
[root@pkiserver1 pki-cert-cli]# ls -l /opt/juno/lib/
total 48
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5355 Sep 10 13:13 gen_cert_request.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5772 Sep 10 13:14 gen_cert_request.pyc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Sep 10 13:08 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  102 Sep 10 13:14 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4507 Sep 10 03:41 pki-wrapping-data.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1750 Sep 10 07:28 profile-xml.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   29 Sep  9 09:22 README.md
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  677 Sep 10 07:57 run_pki_commands.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  941 Sep 10 12:05 run_pki_commands.pyc
 drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Sep 10 12:40 tests

 [root@pkiserver1 pki-cert-cli]# python
 Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 25 2014, 10:19:55) 
 [GCC 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7)] on linux2
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import juno.lib.gen_cert_request
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: No module named juno.lib.gen_cert_request
 >>> import lib.gen_cert_request
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: No module named lib.gen_cert_request
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the interpreter your custom search path for module files. You can pass it either as the environment variable [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) or modify `sys.path` from your program, e.g.:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/tmp/juno')
from lib.gen_cert_request import CertDB
```

Comment: I was assuming having '''__init__.py''' should replace the sys.path method ?

Comment: no, `__init__.py` just tells python to treat the directory as a package. directories without such a file are ignored for imports. if you could use it instead of `PYTHONPATH`/`sys.path`, python would have to search the whole file system for directories containing `__init__.py`. see also [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) for the module search path.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to modify **sys.path** variable.

```
sys.path.append('/tmp/juno')

from lib.gen_cert_request import CertDB
```

Comment: This looks like [the older answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771516/unable-to-import-python-modules-from-different-directories/25772318#25772318).